# How can I stop events from overlaping? Fullcalendar - javascript

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

eventoverlap: false does not work.

I create the events in a json file. I need that none that the events that already exist or that i create to be allowed to overlap the start or end time.

Thank you for your time.

```
                                                 
<script>
   
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',

    events:'./json/events.json',

    headerToolbar: {

      center: 'addEventButton'
    },


    customButtons: {

      addEventButton: {
        text: 'AGENDAR',
        click: function() {
          
          dados = getDados();
          if (!isNaN(date.valueOf())) { // valid?
            calendar.addEvent({
              title: dados,
              start: date,
              end: date2,
              color: '#378006',
              <br>
              allDay: false
            });
            alert('Agendado!');

  calendar.render();
});
     


</script>
```

Comment: So, if dates overlap, what should happen?

Comment: You can tell fullcalendar to forbid new events to be created which overlap an existing one, that's not difficult. But if, as you indicated, you have existing events in your JSON file which already overlap, what do you expect should happen then? Should one of them not be shown? Or one should be moved ir changed ? Which one? How to decide?

Comment: The events in my json do not overlap. I can’t figure it out how to make new events that someone creates to not overlap existing ones. It should not allow for someone to create the event if the time and date overlaps.

Comment: `The events in my json do not overlap`...OK, well that isn't what you said in your original question. You mentioned not allowing events which already exist to overlap each other.

Comment: Anyway the normal way to do what you want is to let users set the event times using fullcalendar's "select" callback and then use the "selectOverlap" option to prevent new selections overlapping existing ones. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting for details.

Comment: If you want to use a different UI for adding events then you'll need to get all the events from the calendar using the getEvents function (or from your database if you prefer) and check each one to see if its dates overlap the user's chosen dates or not.